# How can I put a picture alongside the chapter title?

Tags: graphics, sectioning, chapters

I'm trying to insert a picture besides the chapter title using this code

```
‎\begin{document}‎
\chapter{for example}
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=20mm]{turing.png}
\end{figure}‎
```

but the picture is inserted in a new line. 
Can I specify a coordinate for inserting a picture there?

Comment: If you want the picture inside the caption, you don't want to float it. Therefore you do not want to use the `figure` environment. You may specify your image command directly into the `\chapter{..}`, though depending on the height it may look very odd. If you need more assistance please provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) and probably a screenshot showing us your desired Output.

Comment: I get "use of chapter doesn't match its definition" if I try that.

Comment: Is this something that will be used for every chapter or just for some of them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use TikZ; the [`tikzpagenodes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) gives you easy control on the positioning using the anchors for the text area:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}‎

\chapter{Test chapter}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=east,inner sep=0pt] at (current page text area.east|-0,3cm) {\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work nicely in a multi column document.

Answer (score 6):

If you specify a graphic in a `chapter` command, you will have to protect that command, so that it will not be interpreted when writing the toc file
Or specify another heading:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{looks odd in TOC \protect\includegraphics[width=20mm]{test.png}}
\chapter[does not look so odd in TOC (because the graphic is missing)]%
        {does not look so odd in TOC \includegraphics[width=20mm]{test.png}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since I'm getting complaints trying to include a graphic within the `\chapter`-command's argument, here's what worked for me:

This is more than anything a hack, But one thing you can do is to include the graphic in the next line and move it up with a negative `\vspace`. You can use any unit, but I believe it's best to use something like `\baselineskip` which is contextually defined rather than an absolute unit like mm or pt for the height of the vertical space. Be sure to include a positive `\vspace` afterwards to avoid squeezing the body of the chapter to the caption.

If you want to have a graphic to go with all your chapters, you can pack all of this into a macro which behaves like chapter except that it expects a second argument referencing a figure, like so:

```
    \documentclass[final]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx, ifthen}

    \newcommand{\mychapter}[3][\empty]{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\empty}}% check whether optional parameter is empty
                         {\chapter[#2]{#2}}% 
                         {\chapter[#1]{#2}}% 
        {\Huge %
           \vspace{-2.2\baselineskip} % move up
           \hfill % move graphic right
           \includegraphics[height=10mm]{#3} % include graphic
           \vspace{\baselineskip} % move down before body starts
        }% delimit scope of \Huge
    }

\begin{document}‎
\tableofcontents

\mychapter[toc title]{A chapter}{Logo-univie}%different title in TOC and heading

\mychapter{Another chapter}{Logo-univie}%same title everywhere

Some text
\end{document}
```

NOTE: Edited to preserve the optional argument of `\chapter`.

Comment: It should be noted, though, that neither this solution nor yours can handle really long chapter titles.